# How to pass data from one page to another with flutter?

Tags: flutter

I figured already how to transfer data from one page to another but I found a challenge...

1. A user has to select one of the matches from pg1 (footballEvent) to go to page2(footballScreen)

[footballEvent pg1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SK6K.png)

2. Images displayed on page2  should be the same as the ones previous selected from pg1,

[footballScreen pg2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yl6D9.png)

3. This is the code I wrote to pass data from pg1 to pg2.
   [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2etq.png
   the problem with this approach is: **leftPlayer[index]**, because only the data on the left it's updated on pg2, but not the data on the right side.
4. This is the code I used inside pg2 to update a team's image  data.imageUrl.
   [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSkFf.png
5. This is how I structured the matches: (and I believe this could be the problem because I'm not using the rightPlayer data on the code(3rd point) to pass data to the 2nd pg).
   [leftPlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTbqV.png)
   and
   [rightPlayer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8jDM.png)

So, how can I fix this?

Comment: please add full code instead of the images of code

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a values to a next screen class constructor.

```dart
Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => FootbalScreen(leftPlayer[index]),
  ),
);
```

`RouteSettings` useful when you defining routing on an app main class and all routing managed in this class. You can read more about routing organization in [Documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/named-routes).

Comment: I already did this, please check point #3

Comment: Are you have situations where data passed and all works correctly?

Comment: I have rightPlayer[index] also, so, how to pass that data too? not only leftPlayer[index]

Comment: You should pass a needed data to a screen constructor, what data send depends on your functionality.